# Is the vacuum spacetime around the Earth curved enough to make particles appear spontaneously?

Tags: curvature, vacuum, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, pair-production

I had a discussion with someone who said spontaneous particle creation had been seen in a lab-vacuum. I told him the spacetime around the Earth is not curved strong enough for that. But I have doubts about that. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> someone … said spontaneous particle creation had been seen in a lab-vacuum.

This certainly refers to experiments with [analog gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_models_of_gravity) such as *sonic black holes*. Those are non-gravitational systems that mimic some aspects of curved spacetime physics. So such experiments could detect quanta of *analogue* Hawking radiation and not a true one, and indeed this has been done, see the [Quanta Magazine article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/what-sonic-black-holes-say-about-real-ones-20161108/) for a non-technical discussion of what is the significance of such experiments for gravitational theories.

> … the spacetime around the Earth is not curved strong enough for that.

The Earth indeed does not produce Hawking radiation and the reason is not the value of curvature but rather the absence of event horizon. There are some subtleties with dynamical spacetimes that sometimes can emit Hawking radiation without possessing  true event horizon, but for static spacetimes the existence of event horizon is a necessary requirement, and Earth (which could be approximated as a static spacetime) does not have one.

The reason for this requirement comes from conservation of energy. When quanta are produced by static spacetime geometry appearance of a photon outside of an isolated body, carrying positive energy $E$, must be accompanied by appearance of *another* photon carrying the energy $-E$ so the net energy is conserved. But existence of negative energy photons is possible only for black holes behind the horizon. Informally, the possibility of negative energies for photons inside black holes can be linked with the fact that inside of a black hole time flows along the radial direction, so the energy–momentum component of a future–directed photon along the direction given by the outside time does not have to be positive.

Comment: I think that a *stationary* detector in a static horizonless spacetime won't detect Unruh/Hawking particles (which is all that's needed for this question), but an arbitrarily moving detector generically does, even if it moves inertially (e.g. in a gravitational orbit around a non-black-hole). Hawking and Unruh's derivations were for special cases with well-defined event horizons, but the general phenomenon doesn't need one.

Comment: An observer on Earth's surface sees a time-dependent gravitational field because of the Moon. Can we estimate the (ridiculously tiny) particle production rate because of this?

Answer (score 2):

The Earth has no event horizon, so it produces no Hawking radiation.

Comment: Done. Re. static detector: If both detector and Earth are static, energy (as measured by static observers) is conserved. But if detector "clicks", this means it has absorbed a quanta of radiation and its internal d.o.f. has been excited. This energy has to come from somewhere, but Boulware vacuum means that all the oscillators of radiation are in their lowest energy state, there is no energy to absorb. OTOH with Unruh effect, the accelerated relative to Minkowski vacuum detector has Hamiltonian with explicit time dependence w.r.t. inertial frame…

Comment: … If it excites, the energy for it ultimately comes from the work done by external forces that are dragging detector on a non-inertial trajectory.